# URL returned from server, not accessible in client angular app

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, video-streaming, html5-video

I am trying to create a video rendering app that stores videos on AWS S3 Bucket and returns the location to the angular app, where I am binding the URL to "src" of "video" HTML tag. But it is not rendering the video.

the angular code can be found below for reference:

[app.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRVOP.png)

```
    source:string = "";
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/video/f82c2d2dd221903182626788fc0a1db3', {responseType:'json'} )
        .subscribe((res) => {
          console.log(Object.values(res)[0]['location']);
          this.source = Object.values(res)[0]['location'];   
        })
    }
```

[app.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZZCf.png)

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2">
          <video width="320" height="240" controls>
            <source [src]='source' type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
        </div>
```

However, when I tried to hard code the location returned from server directly to the "src" attribute, it is getting rendered.

I am not able to understand the behavior.

Comment: Wjat does your console.log shows for res? Have you tried `this.source = res[0]['location']` (without Object.values)?

Comment: There is no error in the console log. I am able to see the URL assigned to the "src" attribute of video tag when I inspect the element. But, the video is not playing.

Comment: When I try to hard code the URL assigned to the element directly in code, the video works as expected

Comment: Can you share the actual link &  the res (or res[0]?

Comment: https://aws-cakee-datalake-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos/f82c2d2dd221903182626788fc0a1db3

res:

{"videoURL":{"_id":"6204212adf3fcc38021e2cb4","location":"https://aws-cakee-datalake-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos/f82c2d2dd221903182626788fc0a1db3"}}

Comment: Ah seems that by doing `res[0]['location']` you treat res' content as array, but if res is an array, then its elements are objects, so they have property `videoURL` at top-level. Go with `res[0].videoURL.location` for url of the first res' element.

Comment: That didn't solve the issue. I was able to bind the URL to "src" using property binding, but  still the video is not working. Not sure why hard coding the URL works but assigning the value dynamically doesn't.

Comment: I observed one thing though. Hard coding the URL inside Subscribe is causing the video to not work. If I hard code outside subscribe, the video plays as expected.

Is angular not able to refresh the HTML with subscribed value?

Comment: After days, finally found the solution. Looks like video tag in HTML has to be re-loaded after binding the URL to "src". Fetched the video tag and called the load() on it. That resolved the issue.